# Pick unique random values and join them in one cell in excel

Tags: excel

I have excel sheet with data, ex: is bellow

```
 A            B            
Text 1      Text 3 Text 1  Text 5    
Text 2      Text 6 Text 9  Text 7     
Text 3      Text 2 Text 4 Text 8
Text 4            
Text 5          
Text 6         
Text 7           
Text 8            
Text 9
```

I want to joint column A value in column B randomly but values must unique (no repeat same value ). As you can see in my above ex: column A values random  joint in column B . i search on internet unable to find any formula or answer. im new so dont now which formula work for this.

Comment: fwiw, if it has to be unique then it isn't random.

Comment: @deccc Are you looking for a macro or just a formula?

Comment: @MichaelVine  formula is batter option for me :) thanks

Comment: @Jeeped  Hi thanks for your time , im new so dont know is it possible or not in excel thats why i ask here

Comment: @Jeeped thanks for your concern, i found the answer given bellow, thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **C1** enter:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1,9)
```

In **C2** enter:

```
=LARGE(IF(ISNA(MATCH({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},$C$1:C1,0)),{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}),RANDBETWEEN(1,9-ROWS(C$2:C2)))
```

and copy downwards.

Column **C** represents a randomization of the digits 1 through 9 *(with no repeats)*.

Then in **B1** through **B3** enter the formulas:

```
=INDEX(A:A,C1) & " " & INDEX(A:A,C2) & " " & INDEX(A:A,C3)
=INDEX(A:A,C4) & " " & INDEX(A:A,C5) & " " & INDEX(A:A,C6)
=INDEX(A:A,C7) & " " & INDEX(A:A,C8) & " " & INDEX(A:A,C9)
```

[image]